# Need to remove the delItem from the toDos array not sure how

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't figure out how to complete this function. I have filtered through to find the variable that matches the id but now I need to match that item to the delItem var and delete it.

```
function deleteToDo(tot) {
        let delItem = toDos.filter((remove) => remove.id === tot);
     /// i need to remove item from toDos array that matches delItem.
        renderTheUI(toDos);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Array#filter returns an array, with all items that match the predicate. Instead of getting the item that you want to remove, get an array without the item by checking that the `id` is not equal to `tot`. Then use the filtered array in `renderTheUI`:

```
function deleteToDo(tot) {
  const filteredToDos = toDos.filter((item) => item.id !== tot);
  renderTheUI(filteredToDos);
}
```

I would suggest moving the call to `renderTheUI` out of the `deleteToDo` method, since it might be very confusing. The `deleteToDo` will return an updated array, and then you can render the new array:

```
function deleteToDo(tot) {
  return toDos.filter((item) => item.id !== tot);
}

const filteredToDos = deleteToDo(2);

renderTheUI(filteredToDos);
```

Comment: ... you may want to replace toDos directly `toDos = toDos.filter(...)`

Comment: @JonasW - `toDos` might be a constant outside the function, or other methods might need the original data.

Comment: shure. not trying to correct you, just wanted to extend the answer a bit

Comment: I know, but I see what you're aiming at. The `deleteToDo` name is a bit misleading. It's more of `renderWithoutAnItem`. The `deleteToDo` should return a new array without the item.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to find the element with `filter` but its index in the array.

```
function deleteToDo(tot) {
    let delIndex = toDos.findIndex((remove) => remove.id === tot);

    if (delIndex !== -1){ // if element was found
        toDos.splice(delIndex,1); // remove the element from the toDos array
    }

    renderTheUI(toDos);
}
```